# how to write delegate with 2 parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, syntax-error

This should be a simple question with hopefully a simple answer.
I am trying to write a delegate that takes 2 parameters but the compiler does not accepts it.

When I use one parameter it works, example :

```
var addCar = new Action<string>(number => 
{ } );
```

but when I use 2 parameters the compiler complaints that he does not know the argument 'number'
The code I tried is this

```
var addCar = new Action<string, decimal>(number, test => 
{ } );
```

The error is "The name 'number' does not exists in the current context"

I don't know the exact syntax for creating a delegate with 2 parameters, so I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: list parameters in brackets: `var addCar = new Action<string, decimal>((number, test) =>  { } );`

Comment: Simple answer for a simple question, works perfect, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the compiler to know if the `,` belongs to the constructor call or to the method signature of the delegate, you should add parenthesis around the delegate signature:

```
var addCar = new Action<string, decimal>((number, test) => { } );
```

Now it reads the delegate as

```
(number, test) => { }
```

instead of

```
test => { }
```

Answer (score 1):

My three variant of `Action` assignment.

```
private void AddCarMethod(string number, decimal test)
{
    // TODO
}

private void AddCarMethod(string number)
{
    // TODO
}

public void Test()
{
    // variant 1 (lambda)
    var addCar1 = new Action<string, decimal>((number, test) => { /* TODO */ });

    // variant 2 (method reference)
    Action<string, decimal> addCar2 = (number, test) => AddCarMethod(number, test);

    // variant 2.1 (method reference short form)
    var addCar2short = new Action<string, decimal>(AddCarMethod);

    // variant 3 (with missing parameter)
    Action<string, decimal> addCar3 = (number, test) => AddCarMethod(number);
    addCar3("X007", 5);
}
```